# Не работает редирект

Tags: php

Подскажите пожалуйста, не работает редирект если содержимое файла =

Мой код почему то не работает.

```
<?php
$file_path = "textfile.txt";
$file_cont = file_get_contents($file_path);
if ($file_cont == 'Тараканы Частное жилье '){
header('Location: /1/obrabotka-tr.html');
} 
else if ($file_cont == 'Тараканы Предприятие '){
header('Location: /1/obrabotka-tr.html');
} 
else if ($file_cont == 'Тараканы Технические помещение '){
header('Location: /1/obrabotka-tr.html');
} 
else if ($file_cont == 'Тараканы Открытая территория '){
header('Location: /1/obrabotka-tr.html');
} 
?>
```

Comment: Ну может быть ни одно из условий не выполняется? Посмотрите `var_dump` что у Вас из файла приходит

Comment: Маршрутизация через содержимое текстового файла... Что-то новенькое.. Проверьте содержимое файла. Есть ли, к примеру, там пробел в конце?

Comment: @vp_arth есть пробел

Comment: @robertobadjo var_dump bool(false)

Comment: Ну и кто такой умный минуснул?

Answer (score 0):

Если у вас файл содержит всего одну строку. то тогда можно сделать так

```
$file_path = "textfile.txt";
$file_cont = file($file_path)[0]; //помещаем содержимое в файл и получаем содержимое первой строки

if ($file_cont == 'Тараканы Частное жилье '){
header('Location: /1/obrabotka-tr.html');
} 
else if ($file_cont == 'Тараканы Предприятие '){
header('Location: /1/obrabotka-tr.html');
} 
else if ($file_cont == 'Тараканы Технические помещение '){
header('Location: /1/obrabotka-tr.html');
} 
else if ($file_cont == 'Тараканы Открытая территория '){
header('Location: /1/obrabotka-tr.html');
}
```

Comment: вывел с помощью print теперь показывает так http://joxi.ru/vAWnLn7H1Z4e72

Comment: содержимое файла можно увидеть?

Comment: Тараканы Частное жилье

Comment: var_dump, пожалуйста. с длиной строки и т.п.

Comment: @vp_arth var_dump bool(false)

Comment: Ну вот, файл не найден, значит. Он лежит в той же папке, что и точка входа? Попробуйте указать абсолютный путь.

Comment: @vp_arth var_dump string(46) "Тараканы Частное жилье "

Comment: @ВладиславСамохин в конце пробел точно должен быть?

Comment: @ЕвгенийНиколаев точно

Comment: @ВладиславСамохин Сейчас тоже не работает?

Comment: @ЕвгенийНиколаев нет, не работает

Answer (score 0):

Просто переведите кодировку PHP скрипта и файла textfile.txt в UTF-8 и все заработает. В Notepad2 сделать это очень просто:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: поменял, редирект не произошел

Comment: Я взял ваш код без изменений, сделал файл textfile.txt, вставил туда это "Тараканы Частное жилье ", и редирект произошел нормально, само собой все было в UTF-8